# Updating Windows Azure Mobile Service Table Entries

Tags: c#, azure, windows-phone-8

I am trying to update a column in Azure Mobile Services on Windows Phone 8 app. The table stores user data and I want to find the user having a specific email and password and then update a column of it. Currently I have:

```
IMobileServiceTable<Item> table = App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>();

        var account = table
            .Where(Item => Item.Email == _email_ && Item.Password == _pass_).
            Take(1).ToListAsync();

        List<Item> list = account;
        list[0].Pursue = pursue;      // the value I want to assign
```

Name of the column I want to update is 'Pursue'. What should I do after this phase?

```
table.UpdateAsync(account);
```

I tried the line above but I get an error (Also the change is applied to 'list'). Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out. I added async keyword when defining the class (required to use await).

```
IMobileServiceTable<Item> table = App.MobileService.GetTable<Item>();

        var account = table
            .Where(Item => Item.Email == _email_ && Item.Password == _pass_).
            Take(1).ToListAsync();

        List<Item> list = await account;
        list[0].Pursue = pursue;

        await table.UpdateAsync(list[0]);
```