# update table in Azure Mobile Service

Tags: azure, windows-phone-8.1, azure-mobile-services

How to update particular record in azure mobile Service.

For Example I have a table in azure called **country** having two columns

- *country_id*
- *country_name*

If I want to update the record with `country_id=5` from USA to United State of America.  How to Perform this.

```
//Global Variable  
  private MobileServiceCollection<country, country> items;
        private IMobileServiceTable<country> todoTable = App.MobileService.GetTable<country>();
    class country
    {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string country_name { get; set; }
    public int country_id { get; set; }
    }

private async void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
var change = await todoTable
 .Where(todoItem => todoItem.country_name == tboxcName.Text)
    .ToListAsync();
  await todoTable.UpdateAsync(change);
    }
```

The above code I tried from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403182/updating-windows-azure-mobile-service-table-entries), but did not find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try this:

```
private async void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
var change = await todoTable
 .Where(todoItem => todoItem.id.Equals(tboxcName.Text))
    .ToListAsync();

    if(change != null){
        var toChange= change.First();
        toChange.country_name="United State of America";
          await todoTable.UpdateAsync(toChange);
    }
    else{
    // you have nothing to change, you might throw an exception
    }
    }
```

In the textbox you should enter the id you want to update, in your case it's 5. Then I make a linq query selecting all the items with Id "5", this gets me a list. 
I check if the list is not void, you would want to threat the case when the list is null. If it's not null I take the first element (as you are in the mobile services the id field is unique in the database, so you don't have to threat this boundary case (although if you really want to be sure it's always better to do it)). 
The first element in the list will have the ID=5, so we change the object updating it's country name to "United States of America" (in your case, you don't care of the previous value, as you are updating a specific ID). Then you update this item. The mobile service API will then issue a patch request, and the database will patch it according to the Object ID.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hey,

sorry, but what is the id of your country? id or country_id? Otherwise just replace todoItem.id by todoItem.country_id...

Comment: Hello,

Oh ok, this should be fine as well as they are somewaht equivalent in that case. 

Could you please write what you have in your database? What is your key? Could you please put a breakpoint to see what is inside the change variable?

Comment: Hello,

I don't get why you have country_id and id in your database. What does these two field are supposed to represent? I am not sure but this might be the issue, as your code should normally work

Comment: Yes, You are right. I changed the table and the code worked . Thankyou you very much. You are really a very nice person.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this C# code!

```cs
private async void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   var filteredRecords = await todoTable.Where(
     todoItem => todoItem.country_id == 5)
     .ToListAsync();

   foreach (var item   in filteredRecords)
   {
     item.country_name="United States of America"; 
     await todoTable.UpdateAsync(item);
   }
 }
```

Comment: `await todoTable.UpdateAsync(change);`   //`**change**` is not recognized. when i changed the **`change`** to `item`. still not working.   Response from mobile service is bad Request.

Comment: plz change only the field with `country_id=5`. in For example in SQL i should write this `UPDATE country SET country_name=United State of America WHERE country_id=5';  please answer for this case @JuanK

Comment: i Know the query should be like this: `var filteredRecords = await todoTable.Where(
      todoItem => todoItem.country_id==5)
      .ToListAsync();  `   But dont know how to update that record.

Comment: after editing still shows **'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceInvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Error: Bad request.**